# display a QMessageBox PyQT when a different combobox /list box item is selected

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a combo box `cbLayer` and a function `do_stuff` of the following form:

```
def do_stuff(item_selected_from_cbLayer):
    new_list = []
    # do stuff based on item_selected_from_combobox and put the items in new_list
    return new_list
```

How can I get a `QMessageBox` to pop up whenever a different item is selected in the following form:

```
QMessageBox.warning(self, "items: ", do_stuff(cb_selected_item))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a method or function that contains this code and attach it to the combo boxes signal [`currentIndexChanged`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged):

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    QObject.connect(self.cbLayer, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self.warn)

def warn(index):
    QMessageBox.warning(self, "items: ", do_stuff(cbLayer.itemData(index)) )

def do_stuff(self, item):
    QMessageBox.warning(self, str(item))
```

I didn't try this but it should get you started. Otherwise have a look at the PyQt examples.

Comment: thanks for the code, here's the final result QObject.connect(self.cbLayer, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self.warn \n def do_stuff(self, item): \n QMessageBox.warning(self, str(item)) 
Would you please change your code accordingly?